# Consul federation doesn't route traffic to remote datacenter on client node failing

Tags: consul

1. Expectation is when client service or client nodes failed in any datacenter then the incoming traffic    should be routed to remote
   datacenter.

I've 2 datacenters [`dc1`, `dc2`], both have been joined using join -

```
wan(consul join -wan server1 server2 serverN)
```

Using `Fabio` for load balancing.

`Consul Federation(Basic)` For remote datacenter query forwarding.

My Infra:  3 Consul servers each datacenter. 2 web servers in the back-end with registered their services and health checks on consul servers in each datacenter. In each datacenter services registered with same name & different ServiceID

```
Server Version: Consul v1.0.2
Client Version:  Consul v1.0.2
```

Client service and health checks: httpserver.json

```
     {   "service": {
                   "id": "SERVICE-HTTP-WEB1",
                  "name": "httpserver",
                  "tags": ["urlprefix-/"],
                  "port": 8000,
                  "check": {
                  "id": "server_check",
                  "name": "CHeck_Nginx",
                  "http": "http://localhost:8000",
                  "interval": "5s",
                  "timeout": "1s"
                  }
            } 
     }
```

In each datacenter, incoming web traffic routed to back-end nginx servers through the `fabio load balancer`.

The issue is when all of client Nginx web servers failed or all client nodes get down in any datacenter. The traffic should be forwarded to the remote datacenter. Instead there in logs I see:

> logs:   [WARN] No route for localhost:9999/

Am I missing anything??

When querying consul members `-wan`

```
## Consul start:
    /consul agent \
    -advertise=10.139.80.88 \
    -bind=0.0.0.0 \
    -advertise-wan=139.59.68.32 \
    -bootstrap-expect=3 \
    -client=0.0.0.0 \
    -data-dir=/var/lib/consul \
    -config-dir=/etc/consul.d/server \
    -server \
    -ui
```

config file: config.json

```
{
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "dc2",
    "data_dir": "/var/lib/consul",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "translate_wan_addrs": true,     # It doesn't affect whether apply or not
    "retry_join": ["10.139.80.89", "10.139.80.87"]      # registered proper using private/public as well    
}
```

consul members `-wan` [correct info]

```
  Node              Address               Status  Type    Build 
Protocol  DC   Segment   dc1-server-0.dc1  10.139.80.88:8302  alive 
server  1.0.2  2         dc1  <all>   dc1-server-1.dc1 
10.139.80.89:8302   alive   server  1.0.2  2         dc1  <all>   dc1-server-2.dc1  10.139.80.87:8302    alive   server  1.0.2  2     
dc1  <all>   dc2-server-0.dc2  10.130.71.114:8302     alive   server
1.0.2  2         dc2  <all>   dc2-server-1.dc2  10.130.71.113:8302     alive   server  1.0.2  2         dc2  <all>   dc2-server-2.dc2 
10.130.71.115:8302    alive   server  1.0.2  2         dc2  <all>
```

[ Registered with both private and public IP as well. No issue with server registration as lan as well in wan]

When I query for remote datacenter or vice-versa result is correct.

```
dig @localhost -p 8600 httpserver.service.dc2.consul

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @localhost -p 8600
httpserver.service.dc2.consul ; (1 server found) ;; global options:
+cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47869 ;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0,
ADDITIONAL: 1 ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096 ;;
QUESTION SECTION: ;httpserver.service.dc2.consul.   IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION: httpserver.service.dc2.consul. 0
IN  A   10.139.240.239      **[NGINX RUNNING ]**
httpserver.service.dc2.consul. 0 IN A   10.139.48.49          **[NGINX
RUNNING ]**

;; Query time: 43 msec ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#8600(127.0.0.1) ;; WHEN:
Sun Jan 14 14:10:31 UTC 2018 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question sounds more like system administration than software development, so it might be better suited for Server Fault.

Comment: Thank you @sapanoia  posted on Server Fault.

Comment: Code refactor. Grammar redaction.